# Почему bind_param() не работает?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, mariadb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
          require_once "../reg file/login.php";

          $db = "mydb1";

          $connection = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);

          if ($connection->connect_error) die("Fatal error");

          $stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO games VALUES(?,?,?)");

          $stmt->bind_param("sss", $name, $genre, $date); //Fatal error:
// Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool
          $name = "Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3";
          $genre = "Shooter";
          $date = "2011";
          $stmt->execute();

          echo $stmt->affected_rows . " rows inserted.<br>";
          $stmt->close();
          $connection->close();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Ошибка: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool**
Что я сделал не так?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/655333/call-to-a-member-function-bind-param-on-boolean-in

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource (or mysqli\_result), boolean given](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423439/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole)